# how to loop through an array of vectors in C#

Tags: c#

I now have an array of vectors:

```
static Vector3[] axes = 
    new Vector3[] { Vector3.UnitX, Vector3.UnitY, Vector3.UnitZ };
```

and I want to loop through it,the code I write is:

```
for(int i=0;i<axes.Length;i++)
 {

    do sth. about axes[i];

 }
```

However,it doesnt work and gets into infinite loop,could anyone help?
thx.

Comment: The code, as posted, will not enter an infinite loop. There must be more to it than that: post a complete sample.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It might be that you are adding a `Vector3` to the array in the for loop.

Edit:
Even though arrays are fixed size you could have code similar to this in the loop giving the add effect:

```
for(int i=0;i<axes.Length;i++)
{
    axes = axes.Concat(new Vector3[] { new Vector3() }).ToArray();
}
```

This will cause the length to increase each time and the loop to go into an infinite loop (more specific to loop until an integer overflow occurs.

Comment: Arrays are fixed size, thus your can't add stuff.

Comment: @Dykam, yes but you can set the value of the array to a new value with an increased value.